# Should I immediately clean my paint sprayer after use?

Tags: painting

I just purchased a Wagner ProCoat sprayer. Used it for the 1st time with Valspar Ultra Zero VOC paint from Lowe's.

Do I need to clean it immediately? I'm gonna use it again next weekend. Is 1-week enough to dry the paint inside the sprayer and clog it?

Side question: What chemical should I use to "flush" the Valspar paint with? Reading the gallon, it says thin with water. So should I just flush my paint sprayer with water?

Answer (score 4):

Flush the sprayer with the appropriate solvent for the material you were spraying -- water for water-borne finishes, paint thinner for oils, alcohol for shellac, ....

Yes, clean the gun as soon as you're done with it for at least a few hours, to avoid clogging. You may be able to just cap the finish cup and set it aside for later.